# Почему не происходит инициализация второй карты?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, google-maps-api, карты

Здравствуйте! На нескольких страницах моего сайта есть парочка карт с разными координатами, но одинаковыми стилями (+ в первой предусмотрено информационное окно, во второй его нет, но есть маркер). Суть проблемы в том, что вторая карта не подключается, хотя на первый взгляд и при детальных разборках ошибок в коде я не нашел. Буду премного благодарен, если вы поможете разобраться с этим вопросом.

P.S. не знаю почему, но здесь вообще ни одна из карт не работает. Просьба смотреть рабочий пример по этой [ссылке](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/qaerRP?editors=1010) на codepen.io

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#map').length) {
        initialize();
    } else if($('#object-map').length) {
        initialize_source_map('object-map');
    };
});
var stylesArray = [{
    "stylers": [
        { "hue": "#0091ff" },
        { "saturation": -50 },
        { "lightness": 19 },
        { "gamma": 0.53 }
    ]
}, {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
        { "visibility": "on" },
        { "color": "#68a2cd" }
    ]
}, {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
        { "visibility": "on" },
        { "color": "#adb4bb" }
    ]
}, {
    "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
        { "visibility": "on" },
        { "color": "#3e7cae" }
    ]
}
];


function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.893998, 33.611301);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: myLatlng,
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        styles: stylesArray
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    var image = 'img/marker-map.png';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });

    var theElement = document.getElementById("address_content");
    var contentString = theElement.innerHTML;

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}


function initialize_source_map(source) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.893998, 33.611301);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: myLatlng,
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(source), mapOptions);

    var image = 'img/marker.png';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}
.contact-right {
  height: 45%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#map {
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
}
.contact-right .content-map {
    overflow: visible !important;
    max-width: 260px;
    /*margin-bottom: 15px;*/
    padding: 25px 25px 25px 30px !important;
    background: rgba(138, 165, 189, 0.9);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 36px;
}
.contact-right .content-map:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 12px 12px 0;
    border-color: transparent #8aa5bd transparent transparent;
}


.second-map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCnqeWjQxuCCKNSawsWyoncvxURVxjf8QM&">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="contact-right">
  <div class="map" id="map"></div>
  <div id="address_content">
    <div class="content-map">
      <p>33 Makarious Avenue,<br>
        Frixos-Christiana Court,<br>
        office 32, Larnaca,<br>
        Cyprus 6017.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second-map">
  <div id="object-map"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Убери амперсанд в конце пути `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCnqeWjQxuCCKNSawsWyoncvxURVxjf8QM` ( у меня почему-то он тормозил).
2. Условие наличие карт подправить.
3. Высоту для второй карты дай.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('#map').length) {
            initialize();
        }

        if($('#object-map').length) {
            initialize_source_map('object-map');
        };
    });

    var stylesArray = [{
        "stylers": [
            { "hue": "#0091ff" },
            { "saturation": -50 },
            { "lightness": 19 },
            { "gamma": 0.53 }
        ]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "on" },
            { "color": "#68a2cd" }
        ]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "on" },
            { "color": "#adb4bb" }
        ]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "on" },
            { "color": "#3e7cae" }
        ]
    }
    ];


    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.893998, 33.611301);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: myLatlng,
            scrollwheel: false,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            styles: stylesArray
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

        var image = 'img/marker-map.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });

        var theElement = document.getElementById("address_content");
        var contentString = theElement.innerHTML;

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }


    function initialize_source_map(source) {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.893998, 33.611301);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: myLatlng,
            scrollwheel: false,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(source), mapOptions);

        var image = 'img/marker.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
    }
```

```css
html, body {
          height: 100%; 
          margin: 0; 
          padding: 0; 
        }
        .contact-right {
          height: 45%;
          width: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
        #map,
        #object-map {
          height: 100%; 
          width: 100%;
        }
        .contact-right .content-map {
            overflow: visible !important;
            max-width: 260px;
            /*margin-bottom: 15px;*/
            padding: 25px 25px 25px 30px !important;
            background: rgba(138, 165, 189, 0.9);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
            position: relative;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 20px;
            line-height: 36px;
        }
        .contact-right .content-map:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            margin: auto;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 0 12px 12px 0;
            border-color: transparent #8aa5bd transparent transparent;
        }


        .second-map {
          width: 100%;
          height: 45%;
          margin-top: 5%;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCnqeWjQxuCCKNSawsWyoncvxURVxjf8QM"></script> 


<div class="contact-right">
  <div class="map" id="map"></div>
  <div id="address_content">
    <div class="content-map">
      <p>33 Makarious Avenue,<br>
        Frixos-Christiana Court,<br>
        office 32, Larnaca,<br>
        Cyprus 6017.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second-map">
  <div id="object-map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за помощь Елена, не первый раз выручаете) Воплотил ваши рекомендации на сайте, выходит следующее: первая карта работает как надо, вторая - отображается некорректно. Т.е. видно что она инициирована, но вид у неё следующий (ссылка на скрин): http://prntscr.com/d2z58h

Самое интересное то, что если убрать `styles: stylesArray` для второй карты, она отображается нормально. Хотя видно, что она не подгружается за пределами изначально видимой области: http://prntscr.com/d2z67r

Comment: Возможно вы знаете в чем причина такого странного поведения? Ссылка на страницу: http://cyprus.890m.com/Cyprus/sale-page.html

Comment: Если честно - не могу понять. Попробовала в примере из вопроса добавить styles: stylesArray и все работает.

Comment: Да, там работает, тоже пробовал... Ок, благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что ты инициализируешь вторую карту **только** если не нашел объект для первой

```
if ($('#map').length) {
    initialize();
} else if($('#object-map').length) {
    initialize_source_map('object-map');
};
```

Для решения, нужно убрать `else`.

Comment: По всей вероятности проблема не только в этом - удаление `else` привело к тому, что отображаться перестала и первая карта..